# Indexing/matching the Date in a DataFrame (Python Pandas) conditional on another one?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two DataFrames (df_small and df_large) with a DatetimeIndex and a similar amount of rows.
However, the timestamps (ns granularity) aren't identical and lets say df_large covers a much larger time period than df_small, however it entails df_small's timeperiod.

How can I match the time period so I can plot them (for example) in the same graph?

An approach similar to this should work somehow?

```
df_small[df_small < df_large[-1:].index]
```

This one yields me an "raise ValueError ('Lengths must match to compare')") though...

Turning df_large[-1:].index into a numpy array on the other hand sets all other columns to NaN i.e.

```
>>> df_small[df_large < numpy.array(df_small[-1:].index)]
Out: DataFrame with all NaN's
```

For reference:

```
>>> df_small[-1:].index
Out: DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-03 06:02:39.369627'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
```

Whereas

```
>>> df_large[-1:].index
Out: DatetimeIndex(['2017-05-03 07:11:41.067240'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
```

Sample Data:

```
>>> df_small
                            Position  Price  Side  Size
time                                                   
2017-05-03 06:00:10.867023         0   3526     1     6
2017-05-03 06:00:10.880251         1   3525     1   349
2017-05-03 06:00:10.888418         2   3524     1   462
2017-05-03 06:00:10.896323         3   3523     1   733
2017-05-03 06:00:10.903938         4   3522     1   962
2017-05-03 06:00:10.913828         0   3527     0   311
2017-05-03 06:00:10.922124         1   3528     0    55
2017-05-03 06:00:10.930258         2   3529     0   440


>>> df_large
                            Last trade price  Last trade size  
time                                                            
2017-05-03 06:00:10.682447            3526.0                2   
2017-05-03 06:00:11.033645            3526.0                8   
2017-05-03 06:00:11.233167            3526.0                6   
2017-05-03 06:00:11.551196            3527.0               14   
2017-05-03 06:00:12.471409            3526.0                8   
2017-05-03 06:00:13.199685            3526.0               11   
2017-05-03 06:00:14.462006            3527.0              237   
2017-05-03 06:00:15.405271            3527.0                1
```

Comment: Please include sample data that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Makes sense ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to generate an index that is the union of the two and use `interpolate` to fill in the gaps.  Mind to use the `'index'` option as it will interpolate based on the index values.

```
uidx = df_small.index.union(df_large.index)
df = pd.concat([
        df_small.Price.reindex(uidx).interpolate('index'),
        df_large['Last trade price'].reindex(uidx).interpolate('index'),
    ], axis=1, keys=['Small', 'Large'])

df

                             Small   Large
time                                      
2017-05-03 06:00:10.682447     NaN  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.867023  3526.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.880251  3525.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.888418  3524.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.896323  3523.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.903938  3522.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.913828  3527.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.922124  3528.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:10.930258  3529.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:11.033645  3529.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:11.233167  3529.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:11.551196  3529.0  3527.0
2017-05-03 06:00:12.471409  3529.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:13.199685  3529.0  3526.0
2017-05-03 06:00:14.462006  3529.0  3527.0
2017-05-03 06:00:15.405271  3529.0  3527.0

df.plot()
```

[image]

---

***Setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

small_txt = """time                        Position  Price  Side  Size
2017-05-03 06:00:10.867023         0   3526     1     6
2017-05-03 06:00:10.880251         1   3525     1   349
2017-05-03 06:00:10.888418         2   3524     1   462
2017-05-03 06:00:10.896323         3   3523     1   733
2017-05-03 06:00:10.903938         4   3522     1   962
2017-05-03 06:00:10.913828         0   3527     0   311
2017-05-03 06:00:10.922124         1   3528     0    55
2017-05-03 06:00:10.930258         2   3529     0   440"""

large_txt = """time                        Last trade price  Last trade size  
2017-05-03 06:00:10.682447            3526.0                2   
2017-05-03 06:00:11.033645            3526.0                8   
2017-05-03 06:00:11.233167            3526.0                6   
2017-05-03 06:00:11.551196            3527.0               14   
2017-05-03 06:00:12.471409            3526.0                8   
2017-05-03 06:00:13.199685            3526.0               11   
2017-05-03 06:00:14.462006            3527.0              237   
2017-05-03 06:00:15.405271            3527.0                1"""

df_small = pd.read_csv(StringIO(small_txt), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, engine='python')
df_large = pd.read_csv(StringIO(large_txt), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, engine='python')
```